# ASP.NET - user-controls repeater

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I am building a Web Application for shopping cart using ASP.NET and I am new to ASP.NET.
One of my close associate suggested me to use the user controls, repeater and master page for faster development of pages.

Can you suggest me reading materials to quickly grasp its usage.

Thanks to All.

Regards,
Justin Samuel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master Pages: Really simple concept and easy to implement. Do the bare minimum of reading then just create one and use it with a couple of pages - you really can't go too far wrong with these. Maybe check something like this out:

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/article/18042

Repeaters: Little bit more involved - more to learn (data binding, basic info on the page life cycle) but still very easy to learn.

simple example can be found on w3c schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_repeater.asp

if you are binding to info from a DB, best to use a datareader rather than a dataset:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210513222547/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050405-1.aspx

Good luck fella

Answer (score 2):

See the following videos / texts which should give you some further guidance on the specifics you require;

[Official ASP.NET Learn: Master Pages](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-7024.aspx)

[Official ASP.NET Learn: Custom User Controls](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-194.aspx)

[w3c - Repeater Control](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_repeater.asp)

Comment: The video related to Master page was really very very nice!

Answer (score 1):

For repeaters:

http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/ASPNET1/default.htm

or

http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-08.aspx

---

And there are a whole slew of videos covering almost anything you want to learn here:

http://www.asp.net/learn/

and more beginner-based learning here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb308760.aspx

Answer (score 1):

All of the above are good answers and links. I would like to add the following since you mentioned you are new with ASP.NET. There is a learning program called Ramp-up from Microsoft, it is basically free community-based online learning, it is great for beginners and developers of all levels:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/rampup/dd861531.aspx